# How to query with 2 or more SQL joins

Tags: join, nosql, couchdb, field, relationship

My CouchDB database has 3 types of data: A, B, C.

- A has a 'b' attribute being an ID to a B, and a name
- B has a 'c' attribute being an ID to a C, and a name
- C has a name

for instance:

```
{ _id:"a1", type:"A", name:"aaaaa", b:"b1" }
{ _id:"b1", type:"B", name:"bbbbb", c:"c1" }
{ _id:"c1", type:"C", name:"ccccc" }
```

I would like to get in one view query all the As, and retreiving the names of its B, and of its B's C (and for instance, I would like to restrict the result to get only the As of which C's name is "cc").

How can I acheive this?

(to get only A and B, the answer is:

```
map: function (doc) {
  if (doc.type == "A") {
    emit([doc._id,0])
    emit([doc._id,1], { _id: A.b })
  }
}
```

but I have no clue to extend to 2nd relationship)

I am also interested with the answer in the case we have a 'D' class, and 'E' class etc with more nested relationships.

Many thanks!

Comment: For a basic one-to-many relationship, you can use view and emit the foreign documents. Otherwise, you'll have to either aggregate your documents to cut the relationships or split your request into multiple queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a generic way, in CouchDB it's only possible to traverse a graph one level deep. If you need more levels, using a specialized graph database might be the better approach.

There are several ways to achieve what you want in CouchDB, but you must model your documents according to the use case.

- If your "C" type is mostly static, you can embed the name in the document itself. Whenever you modify a C document, just batch-update all documents referring to this C.
- In many cases it's not even necessary to have a C type document or a reference from B to C. If C is a tags document, for example, you could just store an array of strings in the B document.
- If you need C from A, you can also store a reference to C in A, best accompanied with the name of C cached in A, so you can use the cached value if C has been deleted.
- If there are only a few instances of one of the document types, you can also embed them directly. Depending on the use case, you can embed B in A, you can embed all As in an array inside of B, or you can even put everything into one document.

With CouchDB, it makes most sense to think of the frequency and distribution of document updates, instead of normalizing data.

This way of thinking is quite different from what you do with SQL databases, but in the typical read-mostly scenarios we have on the web, it's a better trade-off than expensive read queries to model documents like independent entities.

When I model a CouchDB document, I always think of it as a passport or a business letter. It's a single entity that holds valid, correct and complete information, but it's not strictly guaranteed that I am still as tall as in the passport, that I look exactly as in the picture, that I haven't changed my name, or that I have a different address than the one stated on the business letter.

If you provide more information on what you actually want to do with some examples, I will happily elaborate further!